# php select multiple values from list box

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP form as below when I select the multiple devices in the list box and press submit, I see only one value in the backend php script.

In this list box I have couple of values, but only one is passed to backend script.
[image: Form with multiple values in list box]

PHP form:

```
 <br><br>
    Select Devices:<br>
    <?php
<form target="iframe_b" action="/php_src/sendNIDDConfigReq.php" method="POST"
        echo "sending data">
  <fieldset>

    <legend style="font-size:150%"><b>send NIDDRequest</b></legend>
    <br> <br>
 Select SCEF:<br>
    <?php

$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'XXXX';
    $conn   = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("ApplicationServer") or die(mysql_error());
    // Get all the data from the "example" table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT EXTERNAL_ID FROM DEVICE_DETAILS") or die(mysql_error());
   echo "<select name='External_ID' id='id_extID'  multiple='multiple'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['EXTERNAL_ID'] . "'>" . $row['EXTERNAL_ID'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";


send
?>
   <br><br>
    <input type="button" id="select_all" name="select_all" value="Select All">
    <input type="button" id="de_select_all" name="de_select_all" value="DeSelect All">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</fieldset>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#select_all').click(function() {
        $('#id_extID option').prop('selected', true);
    });


$('#de_select_all').click(function() {
        $('#id_extID option').prop('selected', false);
    });
</script>
```

server code: sendNIDDConfigReq.php

```
print_r($_POST);
foreach ($_POST["EXTERNAL_ID"] as $selectedOption)
{
    echo $selectedOption."\n";
}
```

Output:
Array ( [SCEF_Name] => SCEF1 [External_ID] => 123@mydomain.com ) SCEF_Name=SCEF1
External_ID=123@mydomain.com

Comment: `name="External_ID[]" multiple`

Comment: Change name='External_ID' to name='External_ID[]' so the form sends an array of the selected items to php

Answer (score 3):

When you have multiple select dropdown the name should be with '[]' appended like this.

```
echo "<select name='External_ID[]' id='id_extID'  multiple='multiple'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Input Element name as array such as External_ID[]

Comment: Thanks all. It is working

Comment: @ramkriz :  Please upvote.